# How to generate dynamic table in a java class from a list

Tags: java, html

I am working in a application where i have to make an html table in the java class and have to save that in database.I am creating that table in java but the how to generate dynamic row in that table .Using 3 lists.I am giving what i have done,

```
                              +"Interview LineUp"
                              +" <table border ='1'>"
                              +"<tr>"                           
                              +"<td>Interviewe</td>"
                              +"<td>Timing1</td>"       
                              +"<td>Timing2</td> "                              
                              +"</tr> "
                              +"<tr>"                             
                              +"<td>name</td>"
                              +"<td>timing1</td> "
                              +"<td>timing2</td> "
                              +"</tr> "
                              +"</table>"
```

So this is the table i am using in the java class,and i have 3 lists which contains 3 set of information like name,timing1,timing2.Now i want that if there are 3 values in all the lists then 3 rows will be generating.

The lists are

```
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom1 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime1.split(","));
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom2 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime2.split(","));
List<String> listOfinterviewerName = Arrays.asList(intervierwName.split(","));
```

Like i am doing this

```
                          +"<tr>";  
                              for(int k=0;k<listOfinterviewerName .size();k++){
                              +"<td>listOfinterviewerName .get(k)</td>"
                              +}
```

How to do that,in that java class ?? somebody please help .Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I understanding you right, you have to save the *HTML* in a database???

Comment: Your input data is really obscure. What if the 3 lists don't have the same number of values?

Comment: @Andreas yes you r write  the 3 list wil have th same number of data thats sure

Comment: @Andreas can you help ??

Comment: Yeah, it's called a for-loop. If you don't know the for-loop yet, you should continue learning Java before trying something this complex.

Comment: @Andreas yes i know for loop but how this i will  implement because i am getting complilation error when i am trying to append a for loop in it

Comment: Then show us the code you have, and we'll be able to help.

Comment: @Andreas i have edited my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88781/discussion-between-lucifer-and-andreas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+"test"` is not a valid Java statement. What are you adding the text to?

When building a String incrementally, you should *always* use a `StringBuilder`.

```
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom1 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime1.split(","));
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom2 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime2.split(","));
List<String> listOfinterviewerName = Arrays.asList(intervierwName.split(","));

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.append("<html>" +
           "<body>" +
           "<table>" +
           "<tr>" +
           "<th>Interviewe</th>" +
           "<th>Timing1</th>" +
           "<th>Timing2</th>" +
           "</tr>");
for (int i = 0; i < listOfinterviewerName.size(); i++) {
    buf.append("<tr><td>")
       .append(listOfinterviewerName.get(i))
       .append("</td><td>")
       .append(interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i))
       .append("</td><td>")
       .append(interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i))
       .append("</td></tr>");
}
buf.append("</table>" +
           "</body>" +
           "</html>");
String html = buf.toString();
```

Of course, to guard against [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks, you should escape the values.

Comment: The method append(String) is undefined for the type String its showing

Comment: Not following you. The code is not doing an append(String) on a String anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was not so clear about your question, but as per what I understood, the code below will work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String s =  ""+"Interview LineUp"
               +" <table border ='1'>"
               +"<tr>"                           
               +"<td>Interviewe</td>"
               +"<td>Timing1</td>"       
               +"<td>Timing2</td> "                              
               +"</tr> "
            ;

    String interviewTime1="11:30,12:30";
    String interviewTime2="13:30,15:00";
    String intervierwName="Adam,Smith";
    List<String> interviewTimingToFrom1 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime1.split(","));
    List<String> interviewTimingToFrom2 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime2.split(","));
    List<String> listOfinterviewerName = Arrays.asList(intervierwName.split(","));
    for(int i=0;i<interviewTimingToFrom1.size();i++)
    {
        s = s.concat( "<tr>"
                +"<td>"+listOfinterviewerName.get(i)+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i)+"</td> "
               +"<td>"+interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i)+"</td> "
               +"</tr> ");
    }
    s=s.concat( "</table>");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: @lucifer this will work for you... upvote and accept answer if it works.

Comment: Doing `String = String.concat(String)` (or `String += String`) in a loop is bad for performance. Always use a `StringBuilder` when incrementally building a String in a loop.